# Python turtle.screen is not able to load the screen.shape() of an image on python 3.10

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-turtle

Since the image is in the same directory. Event its not showing any errors

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

screen = Screen()
screen.title("U.S. States Game")
image = "blank_states_img.gif"

screen.addshape(image)
screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Same directory as what?  Remember that when this is run, it will look in whatever the current directory for the process is, NOT the directory with the source.  You CAN do that by parsing `__file__` to get the path to the source.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but I realised that I was missing the turtle.shape(image)

Answer (score 1):

Your code registers a shape (`addshape` is an alias of `register_shape`), but it never sets the registered shape to a turtle with [`turtle.shape()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.shape).

```py
from turtle import Screen, Turtle


screen = Screen()
screen.title("U.S. States Game")
screen.addshape("blank_states_img.gif")
t = Turtle()
t.shape("blank_states_img.gif")
screen.exitonclick()
```

Another option you may be interested in is [`bgpic`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.bgpic), which sets the background picture. This doesn't require registration.